# SharePoint 2010: Trimming page content based on group

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, trim, security-trimming

In SharePoint 2010, what are the best practices for trimming content on a single page based on group?  For example, I have two types of customers that each belong to a different group.  I only want customer 1 to see their content (links, text, etc), and I only want group 2 to see their content.  I could put this content on separate pages, but some customers will belong to both groups, and it makes sense to display all of this info on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how much of an issue Security is.

You could use Audiences to restrict content displayed with the Content Query Web Part - but this is not a security restriction.

Another option is to store the content is separate lists, with permissions restrictions on the lists, and surface the information through CQWPs, standard List Views or XsltListViewWebParts.

However back in SharePoint 2010 Beta an error was thrown if there was a web part pointing to a list you didn't have access to now, but I'm not sure if that was fixed as a bug or if it remains as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think this page will provide the answer you're looking for, so long as you can use SharePoint designer:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/jquery-to-the-rescue-displayinghiding-content-based-on-user-permissions-or-when-edit-items-permissions-dont-work.aspx